# CSS background-color transition not working well

Tags: css

Hello I have this code: when hovering on the `a` tags the transition works, but text disappears. How I can fix this problem?

```
<header>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">brands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<style type="text/css">

header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333946;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #333946;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a "text-color" to your hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `color` like this  :)

```
a:hover{
background-color:#333946;
opacity:0.5;
border-radius:3px;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You set the `color: #333946` on your links (`header ul li a`), so when you animate the background color with `background-color: #333946`, the text fades into the background because they end up with the same color. Add `color: (something else)` in below `background-color`.

Answer (score 2):

the opacity workes on the whole element also the text inside

change your code like this

```
<header>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">brands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">galery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

header ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333946;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

a:hover{
    background-color:rgba(51,57,70,0.5);
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

the `background-color:rgba(51,57,70,0.5);` is the solution you need